# Calculating the big-O complexity of this string match function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

can anyone help me calculate the complexity of the following?
I've written a strStr function for homework, and although it's not part of my homework, I want to figure out the complexity of it.

basically it takes a string, finds 1st occurence of substring, returns it's index,
I believe it O(n), because although it's double loop'd at most it'll run only n times, where n is the length of s1, am I correct?

```
int strStr( char s1[] , char s2[] ){
    int haystackInd, needleInd;
    bool found = false;
    needleInd = haystackInd = 0;

    while ((s1[haystackInd] != '\0') && (!found)){
        while ( (s1[haystackInd] == s2[needleInd]) && (s2[needleInd] != '\0') ){
            needleInd++;
            haystackInd++;
        }
        if (s2[needleInd] == '\0'){
            found = true;
        }else{
            if (needleInd != 0){
                needleInd = 0;

            }
            else{
                haystackInd++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (found){
        return haystackInd - needleInd;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "Big O complexity"

Comment: Independently of the runtime, this code is incorrect.  Try searching for "cocoa" in the string "cococoa."  You may want to look into the KMP algorithm, which is a modification of the above algorithm to handle cases like "cocoa" where a failure might indicate a partial match.

Comment: Yes, sorry, english isn't my native :)

Comment: Which argument is the main string and which is the search string? Please name your arguments more clearly ;-)

Comment: @Cameron: Since `haystackInd` is used for `s1` and `needleInd` is used for `s2`, I assume s1 is the main string (haystack) and s2 is the search string (needle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed O(n), but it is also not functioning properly. Consider finding "nand" in "nanand"

There is an O(n) solution to the problem though.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the outer loop could run 2n times (each iteration increments haystackInd at least once OR it sets needleInd to 0, but never sets needleInd to 0 in 2 successive iterations), but you end up w/ the same O(n) complexity.

Comment: If N is the length of s1, every iteration does a comparison, search fails, and needleInd gets reset at least once, there will be >N comparisons, but no more than 2N.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes- On each iteration, a comparison is made and either (1) both indices advance, or (2) a failure occurs and the needle pointer is reset, or (3) a failure occurs and the haystack pointer is bumped.  If (2) is followed by (3), then the same character in the haystack string may be compared against two different characters instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm isn't correct. The indices, haystackInd, in your solution are incorrect. But your conclusion based on your wrong algorithm was right. It is O(n), but just it can't find the first occurrence of the substring. The most trivial solution is like yours, compare string S2 to substrings starting from S1[0], S1[1],...And the running time is O(n^2). If you want O(n) one, you should check out KMP algorithm as templatetypedef mentioned above.